# CBP marked on my visiting visa, can I entry US again

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I have traveled to the US 4 times already in 9 months to visit my daughters and have stayed there almost 8 months.  CBP blocked me and marked my visiting visa staying they won't let me enter on my next trip.

But I need come back my home country for my business for 2 weeks every 3 months.  Can I come back again if I leave soon.

Comment: What was written on your visa? Exactly what did the CBP officer tell you?

Comment: Why should you not be able to travel to your home country? Or are you asking if you can enter the US again? Because you've already been told you can't.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that you have spent 8 out of the last 9 months in the USA on a visitors visa is going to be a big red flag to CBP that you are in fact trying to live in the USA not simply visit.

I would say you are lucky they let you in this last time. But if they marked your visa for no further entries, likely your only course of action will be to return home and look into immigration possibilities so you can live with your family.

Comment: It's strange, but I know 2 other people who did almost exactly the same thing with exactly the same result, asking and staying for repeated stretches of several months in the US separated by a few weeks out. Just like the OP, on the trip that got both close to a year in the country they were still allowed in but limited to the time requested and, being Canadians with no visas to cancel, told not to return for a year after that trip. It's quite fair, actually, leaving no entry refusals on the records of people who've been compliant but have clearly worn out their welcome as a visitor.